# Content Builder images

Tags: marketing-cloud, url, content-builder, images

I now have another issue with the same set of images that I had uploaded initially for this template. I deleted them all because I changed my  Setup--> Feature Settings --> Content Builder Settings --> Predictable file URL's to enabled and I would like to use the uploaded file name as the end of the URL path for the published file. So, now when I try to upload the same set of images with the same filenames, I get an error that the filenames already exist even though I have deleted them. I know they get hosted on the mktg cloud domain, but If I delete them from Content Builder shouldn't they also get deleted from the place where they are being hosted ? How do I get around this ? I have 74 image files and I don't want to be sitting here changing file names. Also, lastly I hope I don't have to create another case.

Comment: I think you are going to need to create another case unfortunately. It sounds like the image names were cached in some capacity and are viewing those images as still existing even though they were deleted. You will likely need to have support take care of this for you or rename them.

Comment: Thanks! @Gortonington. Yes I did create a support case and support is helping me with deleting those images from the back end.